# Chrome on Android doesn't scale images to screen

Tags: android, google-chrome

It seems that every other mobile browser will scale images to the screen widths if you browse directly to the image (not to a page holding the image, but directly to the image), so long as the image is as wide or wider than the display resolution. Chrome on Android, however, scales the image much smaller to the upper-left corner of the screen. We've tested this on multiple devices all running the latest version of Chrome.

Since I can't seem to find any resolution to scale the images at that they would appear in Chrome as desired, does anyone have any methods to use a page to hold the image so that it would scale to the device width, no matter the OS or browser?

Thanks in advance,
Beems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have raised a bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=180239

A potential solution would be to create a webpage with the image in and the viewport set to the width of the image.

For example

```
<doctype html>    
<html>
  <head>
     <style>* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}</style>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=[WIDTH OF IMAGE HERE]" />
  </head>
  <body>
     <img src="[URL of IMAGE]" width="100%" />
  </body>
</html>
```

See the sample I have here http://jsbin.com/ilequn/latest

Comment: That will work dandy for now, your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you star that bug you will get notifications when there are updates.

Comment: Your bug has been marked as a duplicate for this bug report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=173148